# Is there a way to get the selected combinations without using if-else if

Tags: java

I am trying to get the selected combination of choices in Java. Here's what I have tried so far. Any of `x`,`y`, and `z` is in selected state if their values > 0.

```
int xSelected = getX() > 0 ? 1 : 2;   // An indicator showing X was selected or not.
int ySelected = getY() > 0 ? 3 : 4;
int zSelected = getZ() > 0 ? 5 : 6;

int selectedCombination = xSelected | ySelected | zSelected; // Not sure what to use here

if( selectedCombination == <someValue> ) // Print <x> and <y> are the selected values
else if ( selectedCombination == <someOtherValue> ) // Print <x> and <z> are the selected values likewise.
```

I want to avoid using multiple `if-else` statements checking for the selected combinations. Like,

```
if( getX() > 0 && getY() > 0 ) // doThis
else if( getX() > 0 && getZ() > 0 ) // doThat
```

Can I do this with bit operations or any suggestion to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to avoid using multiple if-else statements checking for the selected combinations.
>
> [...]
>
> Can I do this with bit operations or any suggestion to do this.

You can form a bitmask that reflects the combined selection status in one integer, though your particular attempt to do that is broken.  It should be more like this:

```
int selectedCombination =
        ((getX() > 0) ? 1 : 0)
        | ((getY() > 0) ? 2 : 0)
        | ((getZ() > 0) ? 4 : 0);
```

Note the use of power-of-two values 1, 2, and 4, each of which has exactly one bit set in its binary representation, and the alternative value zero (which has no bits set) in every case.

Each combination of selections then gives you a different number between 0 and 7.  You can, for example, use a single `switch` construct to select a course of action corresponding to each one:

```
switch (selectedCombination) {
    case 0:
        // no selections ...
        break;
    case 1:
        // only X ...
        break;
    case 2:
        // only Y ...
        break;
    case 3:
        // X and Y ...
        break;
    case 4:
        // only Z ...
        break;
    case 5:
        // X and Z ...
        break;
    case 6:
        // Y and Z ...
        break;
    case 7:
        // X, Y, and Z ...
        break;
    default:
        assert false : "can't happen";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use bit operations, use 1, 2, 4, etc as the values

```
int xSelected = getX() > 0 ? 1 : 0;   // An indicator showing X was selected or not.
int ySelected = getY() > 0 ? 2 : 0;
int zSelected = getZ() > 0 ? 4 : 0;

int selectedCombination = xSelected | ySelected | zSelected;
```

That way, each of the combinations will add up to a different number.

To check just some of them, you can use the `&` operator; for example, `selectedCombination & 5` will select just x and z, ignoring whether y is selected.

Answer (score 1):

For the bit operations you need to thing of shifting bits to make them independent.

```
int xSelected = getX() > 0 ? 0 : 1;   
int ySelected = getY() > 0 ? 0 : 1;
int zSelected = getZ() > 0 ? 0 : 1;

int choices = xSelected + (ySelected << 1) + (zSelected << 2);
```

Now the choices are packed together.

```
bool xAndY = (choices & xyMask) == xyMask;
```

The corresponding values

```
z y x   sum
0 0 0 = 0
0 0 1 = 1
0 1 0 = 2
0 1 1 = 3
1 0 0 = 4
1 0 1 = 5
1 1 0 = 6
1 1 1 = 7
```

So you can see the xyMask is 3, and the bool xAndY would be true for 3 or 7.

Notice in your technique ~x + y is the same integer value as x + ~y. When you use different powers of two, the sum will be independent.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: the below solution may be overkill if you have few cases to handle, but may come handy if you actually have several combinations to handle.

I would make a simple class:

```
public class Selection {
    private final String name;
    private final boolean selected;

    public Selection(String name, boolean selected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
    }
    //getters getName() and isSelected()
}
```

That I would instantiate like this:

```
List<Selection> selections = new ArrayList<>();
selections.add(new Selection("X", getX() > 0);
selections.add(new Selection("Y", getY() > 0);
selections.add(new Selection("Z", getZ() > 0);
```

Then I would create a `Map<String, Runnable>` containing the actions to be executed depending on the selection:

```
Map<String, Runnable> actionsBySelection = new HashMap<>();
actionsBySelection.put("X,Y", () -> System.out.println("X and Y"));
actionsBySelection.put("X,Z", () -> System.out.println("X and Z"));
actionsBySelection.put("Y,Z", () -> System.out.println("Y and Z"));
//etc.
```

Then I would determine the action by streaming into the list:

```
String selection = selections.stream()
        .filter(Selection::isSelected)
        .map(Selection::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

(note: the above loop will create a string with all the actions which are selected separated by a comma. For example, if `X` and `Z` were selected, you would get `X,Z`).

... and run the corresponding action based on that:

```
actionsBySelection.get(selection).run();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need such logic. But taking the problem at face value I'd say there are lots of ways of doing this and whatever you do will look ugly or over-engineered or both!

There's an 8 way branch. It's never going to be pretty!

I state upfront if someone has told you if or if/else are 'anti-patterns' or 'a code smell' or something other disparaging comment, just ignore them and implement what is natural to you.

People tie themselves in knots trying to avoid if and if/else and produce code that is no more flexible, maintainable or understandable and often less so.

It will turn out to be a matter of taste and so long as you layout the tree of if statements I suspect will objectively be the easiest to work with.

The solutions above that mangle the flags and implement a switch statement do work.
But they read like a coding challenge that avoids the obvious, simple and entirely workable solution of nesting if statements.
There's nothing clear and readable about them!

Other answers here mangle the 3 values into a single value and use a `switch`.
Another builds a 'dispatch table' to a 'method' class.
A further variant could build a 3-D array and index it.

Apart from being obscure there's little reason based on the 'brief' to think any of these is anything other than over complicated.

They're an 8-way branch with extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int xSelected = getX() > 0 ? 0b001 : 0; // 1 : 0
int ySelected = getY() > 0 ? 0b010 : 0; // 2 : 0
int zSelected = getZ() > 0 ? 0b100 : 0; // 4 : 0

int selectedCombination = xSelected | ySelected | zSelected; // Bitwise OR 000..111

switch (selectedCombination) {
case 0b101;
    System.out.println("positive X, Z");
    break;
case 0b011:
```